# Environment variables in PyCharm Jupyter

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

In the standard Python Console or Terminal in PyCharm it is pretty straightforward to set environment variables.

How can you set environment variables for PyCharm's managed Jupyter?

Answer (score 7):

There is no easy built-in way at the moment, I am afraid. See the corresponding ticket in the JetBrains issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2770 (and vote for it).

The one workaround that comes to mind is to export the desired environment variables in a shell session -> start PyCharm from it -> start the managed server. IDE will inherit the envs from the shell, and the server will inherit them from the IDE.

Comment: Quite sad thinking they are working on DataSpell for so long and have not covered this feature in the version that is on PyCharm Pro

Answer (score 5):

More a workaround than a solution, one can use `python-dotenv`.

Put an `.env` file with the variables in the directory of the notebook and in the code

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

More on this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75422464/4653485).

A typical `.gitignore` will exclude `.env` files from a git repo.

The downside is the dependency to `python-dotenv` (although the import can be try/excepted if not needed in production).

Answer (score 4):

This feature was added to PyCharm 2023.2 (see [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2770) and [the changelog](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/)) but it is restricted to PyCharm Pro.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a configured Jupyter Server.

- Open a terminal in PyCharm
- Export your environment variables in the terminal

  export MY_VARIABLE="its-value"
- Start a Jupyter Server

  jupyter notebook --no-browser
- Configure PyCharm to use the server you just started

Note the server URL from the terminal output and then add a server configuration in Languages & Frameworks => Jupyter => Jupyter Servers

Answer (score 1):

As [Jerome says](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/2023-2/), it is now in PyCharm Professional 2023.2 and therefore in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2023.2 as well.

Just adding an extra answer to give a screenshot and correct the link which, since 2023.3 came out is now stale. The link is here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/2023-2/

[image]

The easiest way to get to this dialog is to click on the dropdown for the Jupyter server in the toolbar and hit Configure... (this works in Ultimate and PyCharm)
[image]

*Caveat* If you upgrade to Ultimate 2023.3, you can expect to his [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-339962/Jupyter-Notebook-support-broken-in-233.11799.241), where Jupyter Notebooks *will not open*. The workaround (described in the ticket) is to install the official JetBrains Jupyter plugin from the Plugin Marketplace - worked for me.